# Delete from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure of my database :

Posts

```
-> Key
   -> PostId
   -> PostName
   -> PostDescription
   -> PostDescription2
   -> Location
   -> Author
   -> Date

-> Key
   ->
   ->
   ....
```

Somehow the field `PostDescription` has been duplicated in `PostDescription2`, I have n such nodes and I want to delete all entries of `PostDescription2` from all the nodes. How can I do this ?

I did some search on google, but most articles tells about how to delete a child node or fields inside them using some logic in query. Also, I am a bit new to firebase.

Comment: You will need to execute a query to [get all the relevant nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events), then [loop over them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), and [remove the property from each](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields). If you're having a hard time with any of these steps, show what you've tried. That'll make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Frank, the issue is resolved. I was just taking the wrong reference from the database.

Comment: Hi @Frank, Is there a way to query Firebase Database from the console just like aws provides for DynamoDB ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to execute this function ones. (Seams so)  A sample of deletion code may look like into ie: `posts` path:

```
  var dB =  firebase.database();
  var dBRef =dB.ref('posts');
    dbRef.once('value', snpsht=>{
      snpsht.forEach(dp =>{
          var key = dp.key;
          dB.ref('posts/' +  key + '/PostDescription2').set(null);
      })
})
```

This will delete all `PostDescription2` field with setting value `null`. Consider that posts path is not a big data to avoid blocking the code. If so, you may get data with `limitToLast` option like:

```
var dBRef = dB.ref('posts').orderByChild('PostDescription2').limitToLast(1000);
```

This command will order the list by `PostDescription2` and null value for the specified child key come first. and we collect from last 1000 items with above code.

Comment: Hi, just new to firebase. Can this function be called from firebase console ? if yes, how ?

Comment: I think there is no such an option at console.  But there is another direct way without codding. Download database at console (as json). Edit json file with json editor. ( I use Brackets) you may remove all at this editor. Than load this file over exist database through console.  (Be careful  and always make a copy of your data before editing)

Comment: I am not sure, but there must be a simpler way to do this from the console.